# How do I select the data I need from this api?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, fetch-api

I am trying to connect this public API to my website. I got it working, but it gives me all the "buy" and "sell" data.
When in reality I only want to obtain the purchase and sale data of the blue dollar, official dollar, dollar counted with liquid, dollar bag, solidarity dollar.

Use the following code with fetch:

```js
function fetchData() {
    fetch("https://www.dolarsi.com/api/api.php?type=valoresprincipales")

    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        const html = data
        .map(user => {
           
            return `
            <div class="user">
                <p>Compra: ${user.casa.compra}</p>
                <p>Venta: ${user.casa.ventas}</p>

          </div>
          `;
        })
        .join("");
        console.log(html);
        document
        .querySelector('#price')
        .insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html); 

    });


}

fetchData();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```js
function fetchData() {
  fetch("https://www.dolarsi.com/api/api.php?type=valoresprincipales")

    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      const filteredOutput = data.filter(item => {
        switch (item.casa.nombre) {
          case "Dolar Blue":
          case "Dolar Oficial":
            return item;
            break;
          default:
            return null;
        }
      })
      let html = "";
      filteredOutput.forEach(item => {
        html += "<div class=\"user\">";
        html += "<p>"+item.casa.compra + "</p>";
        html += "<p>Venta:" + item.casa.venta + "</p>";
        html += "</div>";
      })

      document
        .querySelector('#price')
        .insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html);
    });
}

fetchData();
```

```html
<div id="price"></div>
```

For the different value of nombre, you can add more filter in the switch-case loop.

Comment: Thank you brother, you have saved me!

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```js
function fetchData() {
    fetch("https://www.dolarsi.com/api/api.php?type=valoresprincipales")

    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        const html = data
        .map(user => {
           if(["Dolar Blue", "Dolar Oficial", "Dolar Contado con Liqui", "Dolar Bolsa"].indexOf(user.casa.nombre) !== -1) {
              return `
              <div class="user">
                  <p>Compra: ${user.casa.compra}</p>
                  <p>Venta: ${user.casa.venta}</p>

            </div>
            `
           } else {
            return '';
           };
        })
        .join("");
        console.log(html);
        document
        .querySelector('#price')
        .insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html); 

    });
}

fetchData();
```

```html
<div id="price"></div>
```

Using an if condition inside the map function will allow you to filter the data to what you're looking for. By creating an array of the names you are interested in, you can only include results which have names you listed.

Comment: Yes! its Works! Do you know how to correctly add more?

Comment: @FedericoAPPPEDIDO Sorry, you did give a list. I've updated the answer to show you how. Please add Solidarity dollar (I can't see that one in the data)  :)